# c: type name is not allowed

Tags: c, struct

I have created this struct:

```
typedef struct Adressbook
{
    char surname[MAX_CHARS];
    char lastname[MAX_CHARS];
    char postalCode[MAX_CHARS];
    char place[MAX_CHARS];
    char street[MAX_CHARS];
    char telephoneNumber[MAX_CHARS];
    char email[MAX_CHARS];
    typedef struct Adressbook *next;
}Adressbook;
```

And this public struct Pointer:

```
struct Adressbook *Start = NULL;
```

But when I try to do this in my under program:

```
Start->next = NULL;
```

I get this error:

```
Error C2273: 'Function format conversion': Inadmissible on the right side of the operator '->'
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you really want that `typedef` in `typedef struct Adressbook *next;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined struct Adressbook as a typedef.  From that point on, you can use it without specifying the struct qualifier.

```
struct Adressbook *Start = NULL;
```

can be:

```
Adressbook *Start = NULL;
```

Also, your member:

```
typedef struct Adressbook *next;
```

should not have the typedef keyword.

Also, before accessing the ->next member of the Start variable, you must make sure it is non-null; that is, allocate memory for it.  Or you could just do, depending on your needs:

```
Adressbook Start;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `typedef` from `typedef struct Address * next`. Also, you can simply declare a pointer `*Start` like so;

`Adressbook *Start = NULL;`

You also need to allocate it memory. `Start->next = NULL;` will give a SEGV fault.

Here;

`Start = (Adressbook *) malloc (sizeof (Adressbook));`

Then you can make assignments to its members.